# how to delete a custom page created after its usage

Tags: inno-setup

Iam creating a custom page using TOutputMsgWizardPage. I wanted to show some values from a file to the custom page. My installers flow is like this,

It will accept a license file from the user and will validate the license file and create an ini file based on license. The ini file contains many information about the license. So after creating the ini file, the next action is to create a custom page to show the information in the ini file to the user. Iam using TOutputMsgWizardPage for this purpose. So after showing the license information i need the custom page to be deleted, (means when a back button is cliked from the custom page.) So each time the user gives a license file, a new custom page will be created. and when back button is clicked, the page need to be removed or deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't create or delete wizard pages once the install has started.
Pages are created once at startup in the `InitializeWizard()` event function in their sequence and you then control whether they're shown or not using the `ShouldSkipPage()` event function. You can load in any values you wish to display in the `CurPageChanged()` event function.

See the [this page](http://www.mirality.co.nz/inno/isd.php) for a good tutorial and example.

Answer (score 0):

You may use page.Free() to delete a page.

Comment: This **might be** quite dangerous.